finding no. of days using data of clear afternoons, mornings and rainy mornings, afternoons
Problem: A student studying the weather for $d$ days observed that (i) it rained on $7$ days morning or afternoon; (ii) when it rained in the afternoon, it was clear in the morning; (iii) there were five clear afternoons; and (iv) there were six clear mornings. Then $d$ equals
Context: The problem is part of an Indian mathematics book for high school students named "Test Of Mathematics At 10+2 Level" which is for the preparation of entrance exam for Bachelors in  Maths at an Indian Institute named Indian Statistical Institute.
My attempt:
Each morning or afternoon can be rainy or clear, so each day can thought of as a string of length $2$ which can be $CC, CR$, and $RC$ due to conditions stated in the problem, where $R$ denotes rainy morning if it comes first in the string and rainy afternoon if it comes late in the string and $C$ denotes clear morning if it comes first and clear afternoon if it comes late. As each day can be represented as a string of two letters we can simply add the no. of letters and divide it by $2$ to get $d$,
$$d=\frac{5+6+7}{2}=9$$
Is this solution correct as there was no use of some intricacies which were given in the problem and the solution is too much trivial?

Yes, your solution is correct.
I would have approached it differently.  Let:

$d = ~$ the number of days.

$m = ~$ the number of days when it rained in the morning.

$a = ~$ the number of days when it rained in the afternoon.


Note that by the constraints of the problem, it never rained on both the morning and the afternoon.
So, from the problem constraints, you have that
m + a = 7  Since it never rained in both the 
           morning and the afternoon.
d - a = 5
d - m = 6
---------  Adding all three equations

2d    = 18

